# Use Browser cookies in PHP Curl to log-in to a website

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get some data from a website, this data is only available for signed users, but I'm not able to sign-in using CURL because it uses CAPTCHA, so I'm trying to use the cookies that are generated by me signing up on a browser to let CURL access the pages that are only allowed to signed users.

So let's say that I've copied all cookies that this website has generated when I logged in using my browser to a cookie.txt file.
I have two questions:

In what format should I store the cookies in cookie.txt?

How can I load these cookies for CURL to use?

```
 $curl = curl_init();

 //load cookies from cookie.txt code

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); 
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 

 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 echo $contents;
```

**Edit 1**

```
 $url="https://google.com";
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/Testing/cookie.txt'); 
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10); 
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); /
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);   


 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 echo  $contents;
```

Tried the above code to get an example of the cookie file, but it seems like cookie.txt remain empty.

**Edit 2**

I changed the path for `'/Testing/cookie.txt'` to `__DIR__."/cookie.txt"` and the cookies where generated in the file, I will try to modify them and use COOKIEFILE and see if it will work.

**Edit 3**

Followed the answer provided below, and it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify the format of a cookie file: You can set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "path_to_the_cookie_file")
```

next run a CURL request to any website that sets cookies, then check the format of the set cookie file.

To send your cookies: Then build your cookie file with the desired cookies and use the setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "path_to_the_cookie_file")
```

to make your CURL request send the cookies.

Edit #1: From the official PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style
>   headers dumped into a file.

Edit #2: this is an example of a cookie file generated by CURL ([source](http://scraping.pro/http-cookie-handler-curl/)):

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1452087781  ___suid 2ecfe4287cbeacd8399eaf98bec9ce0b.59089b9d033bc7c6dce8ea2fca139920
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1452865380  all7_user_region_confirmed  1
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1452865380  geo_location    a%3A3%3A%7Bs%3A7%3A%22city_id%22%3Ba%3A0%3A%7B%7Ds%3A9%3A%22region_id%22%3Ba%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bi%3A89%3B%7Ds%3A10%3A%22country_id%22%3Ba%3A0%3A%7B%7D%7D
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1423921380  autoru_sid  ee094d60fa32eada_daf2da69dc79a59b7c8702a29554abbc
.auth.auto.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1421329026  autoru_sid  
.auth.auto.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1421329026  autoru_sid_key  
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1421329026  cc6882cb6b6f0c912cf9589734fcc1e6    
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1452865027  user_name   igor.savinkin5%40gmail.com
.auto.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1452865027  username   igor.savinkin5%40gmail.com
```

Edit #3: What are all those entries in my cookies.txt file? (http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5)

From left-to-right, here is what each field represents:

> domain - The domain that created AND that can read the variable.
>
> flag - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given
>   domain can access the variable. This value is set automatically by the
>   browser, depending on the value you set for domain.
>
> path - The path within the domain that the variable is valid for.
>
> secure - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the
>   domain is needed to access the variable.
>
> expiration - The UNIX time that the variable will expire on. UNIX time
>   is defined as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
>
> name - The name of the variable.
>
> value - The value of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add options for save cookies:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
```

Comment: I'm not trying to save cookies, I'm trying to use the browser cookies to let CURL access pages that are only allowed for signed users. Please read my full post because that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JohnColbir Use Curl with active CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR for authenticate user (send POST with login+password). After that you'll parse site like authenticated user

Comment: what do you mean by active CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and COOKIEJAR? what should cookies.txt contain ?

Comment: @JohnColbir
Add 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');

to your options. File name can be another (s.e. "data.txt").
Then make curl request for emulate "Login" operation.
After that use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE options with same filename, and your curl requests will be as authenticated.